# PHP How to get the id from a file input field

Tags: php, forms

I was just wondering how I would go about retrieving the id from an input type file field within PHP.

```
<input name="images[]" class="browse" type="file" id="0_0">
```

I need to use the id. I previously was using another input

```
<input name="ids[]" class="browse" type="hidden" id="0_0">
```

In conjunction with the file inputs but it was too cumbersome. I had a look at,

```
print_r($_FILES['images']);
```

But that didn't have the id stored. And neither does,

```
$_POST['images'];
```

Is it possible to retrieve the id of the file inputs?

Thanks

Comment: Um, unclear .. I guess this is after you actually posted the form? If so, you can not .. at least with PHP. You can eventually with javascript ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not include the ID you're looking for in the `name`?

```
<input name="images[0_0]" class="browse" type="file" id="0_0">
```

It probably won't break any looping you're doing, and you'll have access to it in the `$_POST['images']` array keys.

As dbf said, it's impossible access the `id` attribute with PHP after the form has been posted.

Comment: Thanks Sara that was exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

No. When you submit a form, PHP will only have access to the name and value of the input element.

However, you can get ids using JavaScript, which you could send to your PHP script using AJAX.